# a weird expectation (time to finish a call and number of calls per minute)

Tags: probability

Given that the average call lasts 3 minutes, and there are on average 30 new calls per minute, can I say that the active number of calls is, on average, 90?

I am aware that E[XY] = E[X]*E[Y] for x and Y independent, and hope to apply it here, but am unsure of how to proceed

Comment: I think you want [Little's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law)

Comment: If calls come in independent and there are enough "responders" to take a call (i.e. one call does not have to "wait" for another call) then the first sentence seems to be irrelevant. If 30 calls get answered in one minute then you can expect 90 calls to be answered in 3 minutes.  If there are less responders than calls coming in (calls have to wait) , then I think there is lack of information.

Comment: @saulspatz remarkable! I thought it was going to be an easy proof, but apparently it is not.

Comment: @imranfat, the question is about ative calls. 30 start per minute, but they might last 1 minute, or 5, or 10. On average, they last for 3

Comment: Yes, I don't think I've ever seen a proof.  I've taken some courses where it was used, but the proof was always "outside the scope of this course."  I wonder if there's a nice proof online.

Comment: [This](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~spyros/courses/IE7201/Fall-13/Stidham-Little-Law.pdf) looks promising.